# External login not working Identity server 4 asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

External service configuration not working with identity server 4.

```
public static void ConfigureExternalOidcProvider(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            }).AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.AppId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                options.AppSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            });
        }
```

In the external controller, the schema is null, but I hardcoded the schema with `IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme` even though it is not working.

```
public IActionResult Challenge(string scheme, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) returnUrl = "~/";

        // validate returnUrl - either it is a valid OIDC URL or back to a local page
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) == false && _interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) == false)
        {
            // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
            throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
        }
        
        // start challenge and roundtrip the return URL and scheme 
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Callback)), 
            Items =
            {
                { "returnUrl", returnUrl }, 
                { "scheme", scheme },
            }
        };

        return Challenge(props, scheme);
        
    }
```

When I click on the Google and facebook button it, never redirects to the google or facebook page.

Here is the result from my debug option

[image]

Google click

[image]

Facebook click

[image]

CSHTML code

```
   @if (Model.VisibleExternalProviders.Any())
                    {
                        @foreach (var provider in Model.VisibleExternalProviders)
                        {
                            <a class="@($"mdc-button mdc-button--outlined ml-1 mb-1 {(provider.AuthenticationScheme == "Google" ? "mdl-button--googleplus google-logo" : "mdl-button--facebook")}")"
                               asp-controller="External"
                               asp-action="Challenge"
                               asp-route-provider="@provider.AuthenticationScheme"
                               asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
                                @if (provider.AuthenticationScheme == "Google")
                                {
                                    <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw google-logo"></i>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-fw"></i>
                                }
                                @provider.DisplayName
                            </a>
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Make sure you have latest apps.  According following webpage TLS is required.  Best to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and get status number of response to help determine the reason for the error.  See : https://developers.google.com/standard-payments/reference/communication-protocol-details

Comment: Where is the definition for Challenge(props, scheme); method?

Comment: ExternalController of quickstart

Comment: Is that debugging snapshot from a "Google" click or a "Facebook" click? If it is for a "Facebook" click then I think the scheme is null because when you call `AddFacebook` you do not specify a scheme name of "Facebook"

Comment: That is from the Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further information it is hard to answer your question, so I am going to start, and then improve on my answer as you give more details. First of all verify that you see a `scheme` query parameter when hovering over the external login button:

[image]

Comment: Yes I can see, I have updated the post please have a look

Comment: Your route parameter for the scheme is called provider by mistake. Change `asp-route-provider` to `asp-route-scheme`

Comment: Hi Aviad P., how did you draw that arrow?

Comment: In my case, the external controller was not accessible due to an invalid route constraint on the external controller.